# How to use a difference cell's value in 'data' field of Sheets QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to write a formula that will run a query on a sheet whose name is the value of a different cell.

I have this, and have tried many iterations of brackets and single/double speech marks.

```
=QUERY((Overview!$A2)!$A$11:$E$1024,"select A where (E = 'Absent')",0)
```

In this case, Overview!A2 is the cell containing the name of the sheet I want to run the query on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a QUERY function on a sheet whose name is specified in another cell, you can use the INDIRECT function to dynamically reference the sheet name from a cell.

Assuming that the sheet name is in cell `Overview!A2`, you can modify your formula like this:<

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT("'" & Overview!$A2 & "'!$A$11:$E$1024"), "select A where E = 'Absent'", 0)
```

Note : `INDIRECT(...)` converts the constructed text string into an actual reference to the specified range on the sheet whose name is in cell `Overview!$A2`

Hope this helps.

[Reference : Google sheets - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

*Use [`indirect()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) as such:*

```js
=QUERY(indirect(Overview!A2&"!A11:E1024"),"select A where (E = 'Absent')",0)
```